# Prove by induction that $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n+i}{2i-3}=2^n(1-2n)$.

Tags: proof-writing, induction, products

Prove by induction that $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n+i}{2i-3}=2^n(1-2n)$.

**What I did:**
It's easy to see that the base case is true. Then I have to prove that if the statement is true for $n$ then it must be true for $n+1$. That is to say, if true for $n$, prove that $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{n+1+i}{2i-3}=2^{n+1}(1-2(n+1))=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n+1+i}{2i-3}\right)\frac{2n+2}{2n-1}=-2\cdot2^n(2n+1)$. Of course the $+1$ inside the product is blocking my progress, because I can't replace it by the inductive hypothesis. I've figured that $-2\cdot2^n(2n+1)=-2\cdot2^n(1-2n)-n2^{n+3}$, but I don't know if that helps.

**Help is much appreciated!**

Comment: The top product terms shift by dropping $n+1$ as a factor and adding $2n+1,2n+2$ as factors, while the bottom product terms increase by adding $2n-1$.  So you need to show that $2^n(1-2n)\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)(2n-1)}=2^{n+1}(-1-2n)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since induction is required, consider this:
$\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{n+1+i}{2i-3}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n+i}{2i-3}\Big(\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(2n-1)(n+1)}\Big) \implies$
$2^{n+1}(2n+1) =  2^n(2n-1) \frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(2n-1)(n+1)}$ is true under assumption, which means assuming the first case is true, induction holds.

Comment: This is it. But I'm missing a step. How did you turn $\frac{1}{2i-3}$ to $\frac{2n+1}{n+1}$?

Comment: @BrKo14 I turned 2i-3 into 2n-1. Then, if you look at the interval of the numerator of both products, the LHS product has interval [n+2, 2n+2], and the RHS product has interval [n+1, 2n], hence you divide out the n+1, and multiply in the 2n+1 and 2n+2

Answer (score 3):

Brute-force induction won't work well here, it's better to approach this problem by looking for simplifications. For example, the numerator in the product can be written in the form $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$ and can be removed from the product entirely, thus leaving $\displaystyle\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2i-3}=2^n(1-2n)$. The same reasoning should be used for the denominator. It is $\frac{1}{(-1) \cdot (1) \cdot (3) ... \cdot(2n -3)}$
which is also $-\frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(2n-2)!}$, so you have $-\frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(2n-2)!}\frac{(2n)!}{n!} = 2^{n} (1-2n) \implies \frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(2n-2)!}\frac{(2n)!}{n!} = 2^{n} (2n-1)$.
Further simplifications show that $\frac{2n(2n-1)}{n} = 2(2n-1)$ which is obviously an equality. Thus the statements are equal. You shouldn't use induction here.

Comment: Induction works, but obviously your direct approach applies.

Comment: Actually induction does work here. OP wants help with the inductive process, so I don't see how a deductive process helps.

Comment: This method is far simpler. No use in over-complicating a problem.

Comment: Even the title says "prove by induction". What if this was supposed to be an exercise in induction?

Comment: Maybe so. I am posing an alternative, simpler solution to the problem posed. Induction, in essence, is more useful in problems with a consistency between cases. The Goldbach conjecture can be written inductively, but that's not much help, as there is hardly a simple connection between the prime sums!

Comment: Nonetheless, I have also proved this problem by induction, in a far simpler fashion than is otherwise posed.

Comment: Sure enough, this is a good answer, but not what I need. I'm required to use induction.

Answer (score 1):

The inductive hypothesis is:
$$\prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac {k+i}{2i-3}=2^k(1-2k)$$
LHS can be written as:
$$\frac {k+1}{-1} \cdot \frac {k+2}{1} \cdot \frac {k+3}{3}...\cdot \frac {k+k}{2k-3}=\left(\frac {k+2}{-1} \cdot \frac {k+3}{1} \cdot \frac {k+4}{3}...\cdot \frac {k+k}{2k-5}\right)\cdot \left(\frac {k+1}{2k-3}\right)=\left(\left(\prod_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac {k+1+i}{2i-3}\right)\left(\frac {2k-3}{2k+1} \cdot \frac {2k-1}{2k+2}\right)\right) \cdot \left(\frac {k+1}{2k-3}\right)=2^k(1-2k)$$
Now simplify the terms other than the $\prod$.
You are left with:
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k+1} \frac {k+1+i}{2i-3}=-2^{k+1}(1+2k)$$
This completes the inductive step.

Comment: It's worth noting that highlighting the $2k-3$ term did not provide any added value in your argument...  Any particular reason you decided to separate out this term specifically?

Comment: Perhaps it is more obvious now.

Comment: What is the downvote for?

Comment: Good question, it wasn't mine.  But it's still unclear why you chose to highlight that term ($2k-3$), since it does not participate in the change from $k\to k+1$.

Comment: Well, in the $\prod$ term the numerator starts with $k+2$, so I decided to separate the $k+1$ term. It was an effort to obtain the inductive step required, $P_{k+1}$.

Comment: The $i=1, k+1$ term from the numerator does not correspond to the $i=k, 2k-3$ denominator term, so it still doesn't make sense...

Comment: It does to me. This was the way I saw that the $k+1+i$ term can be obtained.